# Typeface for the clock on Android pattern lock screen

Tags: android

As the title implies, I am looking for the typeface for the clock when you enter in the pattern. Does anyone know of it offhand or know where I can find it in the source code?

Comment: A screenshot would help. For starters, every device (Google experience, MOTOBLUR, HTC Sense) looks different, and on my T-Mobile G1, there is no clock on the screen where you enter in the pattern (assuming you mean the lock screen). There is the status bar clock visible there, and I would assume that's Droid Sans bold.

Comment: The font you're thinking of is called Storopia. Some thread about this here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=581308

Answer (score 3):

The font is actually a subset of Storopia called "Clockopia" (the subset includes only digits and a few other characters). It will most likely be made available as part of a future open source release.

Answer (score 0):

**Storopia**, the Android Font, is available for download on [deviantart](http://darkfear-10.deviantart.com/art/Storopia-Android-Font-211955622)

It includes all numbers, uppercase and lowercase alphabets and all the commonly used symbols.